# Records are added but all the data is crammed into each record that was added

Tags: javascript, each

The $.each does not add each record's individual record but instead crams all the record's data into each record. 
For instance, the State field has all the record's States crammed into each record.
This is what displays and is exactly what each record has:
19VM5433:151 F3: 38610386113861238613386143861538616386173861838619386203862138622386233862438625386263862738638 Loc: 1234567891011121314151617182 locName: San BernardinoMiamiSouth ChicagoMinneapolisMinneapolisKansas CitySt. LouisWinston-SalemAlbuquerqueLas VegasClevelandColumbusDaytonCarlisleNashvilleDallasHoustonSan AntonioMiami

```
function get_LTMS_Bids() {
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Retrieve all LTMS Bids 
// Bid Detail:                               Carrier Quote:
// fid_62   = Location      - fid_7
// fid_63   = Region                - fid_9
// fid_67   = Location Name - fid_8
// fid_72   = Delivery Mode - fid_17
// fid_74   = Tank Type     - fid_20
// fid_75   = Tank Size     - fid_21
// fid_3     = Bid Detail RID        - fid_103
// fid_85   = Annual Volume - fid_18
// fid_90   = Product Group - fid_57
// fid_105  = Related Bid Hdr   - fid_105
// fid_136 = Nearest Terminal   - fid_55
// fid_245 = Address1       - fid_11
// fid_246 = Address2       - fid_12
// fid_247 = City           - fid_13
// fid_248 = State          - fid_14
// fid_249 = Postal         - fid_15
// fid_269 = Nearest Rack Mkt   - fid_54
// fid_619 = Latitude           - Bid Detail
// fid_620 = Longitude      - Bid Detail
// fid_106 = BH - Solicitation #  - Bid Detail
// fid_679 = Bid Hdr Solicit #     - Bid Detail (formula Text field, same value as fid_106)
//
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var dbid = dbidLTMS;
var LTMS_bid_hdr = $("#_fid_45").val();
console.log("LTMS Bid Hdr: " + LTMS_bid_hdr);
  
$.ajaxSetup({data: {apptoken: apptoken}});
    var promise = $.get(dbid, {
    act: "API_DoQuery",
    query: "{106.EX." + LTMS_bid_hdr + "}",
    clist: "3.62.63.67.245.246.247.248.249.74.75.72.85.269.136.90",
    slist: "3.63.62", 
    options: "num-9999.sortorder-A"
});

$.when(promise).then(function(xml) {
    console.dirxml(xml);
    var F3 = null;
    var F62 = null; 
    var F67 = null; 
    var F63 = null; 
    var F245 = null; 
    var F246 = null; 
    var F247 = null; 
    var F248 = null; 
    var F249 = null; 
    var F74 = null; 
    var F75 = null; 
    var F72 = null; 
    var F85 = null; 
    var F269 = null; 
    var F136 = null; 
    var F90 = null;   
    $.each($("record", xml), function(){
//          console.log("LTMSRID: " + $("record_id_", xml).text() + " Loc: " + $("location", xml).text() + " LocName: " + $("location_name", xml).text());
        F3 = $("record_id_", xml).text();
        F62 = $("location", xml).text();
        F67 = $("location_name", xml).text();
        F63 = $("region", xml).text();
        F245 = $("customer_site_map__street_1", xml).text(); 
        F246 = $("customer_site_map__street_2", xml).text();
        F247 = $("customer_site_map__city", xml).text();
        F248 = $("customer_site_map__state_region", xml).text();
        F249 = $("customer_site_map__postal_code", xml).text();
        F74 = $("tank_type", xml).text();
        F75 = $("tank_size__gallons_", xml).text();
        F72 = $("delivery_mode", xml).text();
        F85 = $("annual_volume", xml).text();
        F269 = $("nearest_rack_market", xml).text();
        F136 = $("nearest_terminal", xml).text();
        F90 = $("product_group", xml).text();
        console.log("F3: " + F3 + " Loc: " + F62 + " locName: " + F67);
        $.get(dbidCB, {
            act: "API_AddRecord",
            _fid_6: "No",
            _fid_106: kRid,
            _fid_103: F3,
            _fid_7: F62,
            _fid_8: F67,
            _fid_9: F63,
            _fid_11: F245,
            _fid_12: F246,
            _fid_13: F247,
            _fid_14: F248,
            _fid_15: F249,
            _fid_20: F74,
            _fid_21: F75,
            _fid_17: F72,
            _fid_18: F85,
            _fid_54: F269,
            _fid_55: F136,
            _fid_57: F90
        }).then(function(xml) {
           var F3 = null;
           var F62 = null; 
           var F67 = null; 
           var F63 = null; 
           var F245 = null; 
           var F246 = null; 
           var F247 = null; 
           var F248 = null; 
           var F249 = null; 
           var F74 = null; 
           var F75 = null; 
           var F72 = null; 
           var F85 = null; 
           var F269 = null; 
           var F136 = null; 
           var F90 = null; 
//              console.log("Add Result: " + $("errtext", xml).text() + "\nerrDetail: " + $("errdetail", xml).text());
        }); // End Add_Record
    });     // End of Each function
});         // End of promise function
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use this format which returns individual records.
F3 =  $(this).children('record_id_').text().trim();

or
F3 = $("record_id_", this).text().trim();